# ctime() causing SIGABRT (?!)

Tags: c, sigabrt, ctime

This is the code:

```
void i_log_ (int error, const char * file, int line, const char * fmt, ...)
{
     /* Get error description */
     char * str_err = get_str_error (errno);
     remove_trailing_newl (str_err);

     /* Format string and parameters */
     char message [1024];
     va_list ap;
     va_start (ap, fmt);
     vsprintf (message, fmt, ap);
     va_end (ap);

     /* Get time */
     time_t t = time (NULL);
     char stime [64];
     char * temp = ctime (&t);
     strncpy (stime, temp, sizeof stime - 1);
     remove_trailing_newl (stime);

     FILE * log;


#ifdef __WIN32__
#else
# ifdef P_LISTENER
     log = fopen (I_LOG_FILE, "a+b");
     flock (fileno (log), LOCK_EX);
# else /* shared file descriptor of log, lock before opening */
     pthread_mutex_lock (& mutex);
     log = fopen (I_LOG_FILE, "a+b");
# endif
#endif

     if (log) {
          if (error)
               fprintf (log, ERR_FORMAT, stime, file, line, str_err, message);
          else
               fprintf (log, ERR_FORMAT_NO_ERRNO, stime, file, line, message);
     }

#ifdef __WIN32__
     free (str_err);
#else
# ifdef P_LISTENER
     flock (fileno (log), LOCK_UN);
     fclose (log);
# else
     fclose (log);
     pthread_mutex_unlock (& mutex);
# endif
#endif
     return;
}
```

Although there is a lock mechanism, in this case the function is not called concurrently, so I think that's not the problem. However, the program receive a `SIGABRT`:

```
[...]
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGHUP, Hangup. // It's OK, I sent this.
0x00dee416 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00dee416 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) up
#1  0x0013ae71 in raise () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) up
#2  0x0013e34e in abort () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) up
#3  0x00171577 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) up
#4  0x0017b961 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) up
#5  0x0017d28b in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) up
#6  0x0018041d in free () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) up
#7  0x0019b0d2 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) up
#8  0x0019b3c5 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) up
#9  0x00199a9f in localtime () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) up
#10 0x00199951 in ctime () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) up
#11 0x08049634 in i_log_ (error=0, file=0x804b17d "src/group.c", line=53, fmt=0x804b128 "Setting up new configuration: listener type: %s, number: %d, http-log: %s, port: %d.") at src/error.c:42
42       char * temp = ctime (&t);
(gdb) print temp
$1 = 0x260000 ""
(gdb) print t
$2 = 1329935482
(gdb) print &t
$3 = (time_t *) 0xbff8a5b8
(gdb)
```

I haven't a clue. `ctime` is returning an empty string, and the man page don't mention this case. And come to think of it, I don't understand why it would return an empty string, and what's wrong with that code.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're probably already calling `ctime()` elsewhere. It's probably solved by using `ctime_r()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ctime` isn't returning an empty string. It hasn't returned at all yet, because it crashed while trying to do its thing.

The crash is inside `free()`, so you're probably corrupting memory at some point before you called `ctime()`. If you're running on a supported platform, try using a tool like Valgrind to check your memory accesses.

Comment: Yes, I corrected a bug with Memcheck (a buf[sizeof buf] = '\0', duh) that was pretty far from where the crash appened. I didn't understand how it was related, but that's it. Also thanks for pointing out to me that ctime actually wasn't returning.

Comment: Subtle memory overruns like that can cause later crashes in memory allocation functions by corrupting data structures used internally by `malloc()` (and `free()`). Once that's happened, it's just a matter of time before the corruption is encountered.

Answer (score 2):

Since the crash is happening down inside `ctime()` and the pointer you pass is valid, the problem is likely that you've already trampled out of bounds with memory (there's `free()` in the stack trace) somewhere else and the problem is only manifesting itself here.

Comment: It's probably a (failed) sanity check on `free()`. I would expect to see some output on stderr (something like "glibc detected double free", or something similar).